Best Practice for Adding Columns to a Table View with Multiple Data Type Options
I am currently designing a new view of a table that sites within a legacy product. The user will add columns to this table which will pull data from different systems. There are 4 types of data they can select.
Once they select a column type a modal will open and they will begin a flow of selecting the correct data they need (Im aware a modal isnt great here either but it's what we have for now.)
Essentially, which component feels correct here for adding?



This question needs more details. It's not clear, why you have a need to add new columns? Why the data is merged and to what purpose?

Is your question to choose between the dropdown and the modal concepts?

Recently I did a heuristic evaluation and a user testing for a client that makes Business Intelligence. In those results a pattern close to your option A came as the best solution. One of the outcomes for that client is that all the other applications that this client has are all similar that's why the pattern A was the best approach to follow with that client. I can't give you the specifics, but I can lead your decision that if the solution that you're designing has a window app and from there you're trying to create some other features option A is the best.
Option B make feel totally disconnected the Modal from the action to create a column.
At this point I think you need an A/B testing session, to take the best decision on your project.
